# What are the approximate values of the minimum and maximum points of $f(x) = x^5 − 10x^3 + 9x$ on $[-3,3]$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

maximum point: $(–2.4, 37.014)$ and minimum point: $(2.4, –37.014)$

maximum point: $(2.4, –37.014)$ and minimum point: $(–2.4, 37.014)$

maximum point: $(–1.4, 33.014)$ and minimum point: $(1.4, –33.014)$

maximum point: $(–3, 30)$ and minimum point: $(3, –30)$

Comment: What do you want us to do?

Comment: Is this yet another multiple-choice question?

Comment: If you just want the answer, then [type it into wolfram alpha.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5+-+10x%5E3+%2B+9x+extrema) This site is not intended to simply provide answers to homework questions without context.

Comment: the equation can be changed $$x^5-9x^3-x^3+9x =x^3(x^2-9)-x(x^2-9)=(x^3-x)(x^2-9)=x(x-1)(x+1)(x-3)(x+3)$$ Now you can find the max and min of this function.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** to get the values of the min and max of $f$, you can derive $f$ and find that $f'(x)=5x^4-30x^2+9$, then solve $5x^4-30x^2+9=0$ (use the change of variables $X=x^2$).

You have to solve $5X^2-30X+9=0$ whose solutions are $X_1 = \dfrac{30+\sqrt{720}}{10}=\dfrac{15+6\sqrt{5}}{5}$ and $X_2=\dfrac{15-6\sqrt{5}}{5}$

Then the points where $f'(x)=0$ are $x_1=\sqrt{X_2} \approx 0.562$, $x_2=-\sqrt{X_2} \approx -0.562$, $x_3=\sqrt{X_2} \approx 2.38$, $x_4=-\sqrt{X_2} \approx -2.38$

And you find that $f(x_1) \approx 3.33$, $f(x_2) \approx -3.33$, $f(x_3) \approx -37.0$ and $f(x_4) \approx 37.0$

You can conclude with these values and the variations of $f$ in $[-3, 3]$.

Comment: Saddle points may exist though...

Answer (score 0):

For a multiple choice question you don't have to solve the problem, though that is one approach.  The second choice cannot be right because the maximum is less than the minimum.  The first asserts the highest max and lowest min, so plug those $x$ values in and see if they come out right.  The polynomial is odd, so you only have to try one.  Bingo.